# Game programming in c++, what's this old line, and why doesn't it work?

Tags: c++, istream

Here's a line of code that I get an error about, which is in my book from 2008: `std::cin.get(std::cin.rdbuff()->in_avail()+1);`

Could someone please tell me what it means and why it gives me an error:

```
In function 'int main()':|7|error: 'struct std::istream' has no member named 'rdbuff'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

--update--

changed rdbuff to `rdbuf`, and it throws this error:

```
walkthrough.cpp|7|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::get(std::streamsize)'|
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied this line from your book correctly? There is indeed no method [`istream::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) which takes only a `std::streamsize` as an argument.

Comment: std::cin.ignore--  omg.  I think I'm dyslexic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member function is called `rdbuf()`, one `f`, as a cursory glance at any [library reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/) will easily reveal.

In other words, the error is that `istream` has no member named `rdbuff`.

Comment: F's are notably [hard to count](http://www.angelfire.com/ak2/intelligencerreport/page65.index.html)!

Comment: Thank you.  Great resource.  I am sure I'll use it a lot, especially when I get this kind of error.  Updated because still getting errors, but this is definitely an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kerrek SB already told you the reason for the error: It's `rdbuf`, not `rdbuff`.

Now on what this code tries to do: It is trying to enforce a blocking read (that is, it tries to force the program to wait for the user to input something even if there's unread stuff which has been entered before reaching that statement). `in_avail` gives the number of characters "available", that is, how many characters you are guaranteed to be able to read without blocking, i.e. without the program having to wait for the user to input more.

However that line of code is somewhat misguided because there's no guarantee that reading the next character *does* block. So it may happen on some system that this line still doesn't wait for user input in some cases.

And even in cases where it does, the input stream will typically be left with a line where the first character was removed, but the rest is available, possibly giving surprising results on further reads if it wasn't an empty line to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, celtschk.  It's a little over my head, unfortunately.  I'm not sure what blocking is. :)

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: "Blocking" just means that the function doesn't return immediately, but only after enough input is available. The typical `std::cin >> name;` is a blocking call, as it will only return once data is available in `std::cin`.

Comment: Is there a non-blocking alternative?

Comment: Anyway, thanks.  I really appreciate the info.  Sorry I didn't pick your answer, but I liked the reference from the other question so much I felt like it should be a topper, celt. :)

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: Well, the function obviously cannot return any data before it is availabe. So the only non-blocking alternative is to check beforehand whether some data already is available; that is, vou'd first check `in_avail` and then only read as much as it returns (as opposed to one more as the line from the book does). If there's no character available (`in_avail` is zero) this means you cannot read anything. Unfortunately that's not really a reliable method either, because in_avail might return 0 even if there are characters available.